# Typescript: Import statement issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

No, it isn't

> "cannot use import statement outside a module"
>
> "CustomError: Cannot find module
> '/L:/Projects/js/npm/prompto.json/typings' imported from
> L:\Projects\js\npm\prompto.json\src\structures\prompto.ts"

what does this even mean? why is there a forward slash behind L?

I have this.

```js
import '../../typings';
```

And it yields that error. Here's my ts-config:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
  },
  "lib": ["esnext"]
}
```

my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "prompto.json",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CL Prompt JSON Generator Tool",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "json",
    "command-line",
    "prompt"
  ],
  "author": "Not For You :P",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure any of this out.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The slash behind `L` denotes root directory in POSIX. How do you run the program? Can you upload it to GitHub? Without enough context it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Behrang I run the file with `ts-node test/index`, because the file im trying to run is in a subdir.

Comment: It means just what it says... there i no `prompto.json/typings` module. `import '../../typings'` isn't a valid import statement for ESM. If there is a `prompto.json/typings.ts` file, the import would be `import '../../typings.js'` (the name of the file when compiled). However, I don't know what you would be attempting to accomplish with such an import anyway... you're not importing any value from it, just loading it. What's in there, why is it outside of `src`, and what are you expecting your import to do?

Comment: I fixed it and it's nothing about what you just described.

Comment: Please read [ask] and amend your title so that it provides a summary of the issue, rather than just saying there's an issue, which of course is what 98% of the questions on this site are.